# Improving SNR (signal to Noise) - sine wave over white noise

Tags: signal-processing

I'm reading a signal which is a constant frequency sine wave (F = 1KHz), constant phase and changing amplitude.
For example, if the read-back signal is "high" the amplitude will be (say) 1V.
If the read-back signal is "low" the amplitude will be (say) 0.01 V.

The signal is deep in white noise (full spectra).
How can I improve SNR to remove the noise but remain with the signal ?
Of course I tried steep filters BPF at the known frequency.

Any other ideas to remove the noise and get a better SNR ?